# Resolve content:// Uri into actual filepath

Tags: android

I'm building an App that manages audiobook libraries

Using the Intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose a Directory as a library, I get an Uri of the form : content:// as a result.

Is there a way to convert the given "content://" Uri to a "file:// filepath" ? ( if that is possible of course )
Or can I tweak the file chooser activity to accept only folders that have an actual file:// path ?

Thank you very much

EDIT : progress !

I managed, using the content resolver, to find a path of the form "1407-1105:Audiobooks" for the SD card, and "primary:Audiobooks" for the main volume. That seems more readable, but I have the same problem still.

Comment: Yes it is often possible. Depending on provider. Post the complete content scheme.

Comment: It looks like 
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAudiobooks`

Comment: Well you can see that it is Audiobooks directory on external storage. Audiobooks directory on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). `/storage/emulated/0/Audiobooks`.

Comment: That's just an example ... I want to convert ANY content:// path that have a valid file:// uri representation.

Comment: The wish is ok. And not possible. And it depends on the provider. And i only told you how to do it for one provider. It could get you started. Its a good feeling knowing that i helped someone ;-)

Comment: My good feeling changed to bad knowing that i did not tell you that it is not done now a days trying to get a real path from uri. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution ! Maybe it is a little bit ugly, but that does seems to work !

```kotlin
fun resolveContentUri(uri:Uri): String {

    val docUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri))
    val docCursor = context.contentResolver.query(docUri, null, null, null, null)
    
    var str:String = ""

    // get a string of the form : primary:Audiobooks or 1407-1105:Audiobooks
    while(docCursor!!.moveToNext()) {
        str = docCursor.getString(0)
        if(str.matches(Regex(".*:.*"))) break //Maybe useless
    }
    
    docCursor.close()

    val split = str.split(":")
    
    val base: File =
        if(split[0] == "primary") getExternalStorageDirectory()
        else File("/storage/${split[0]}")

    if(!base.isDirectory) throw Exception("'$uri' cannot be resolved in a valid path")

    return File(base,split[1]).canonicalPath
}
```